# Angular 7 SSR, App component ngOnInit() called multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have an angular 7 application with about 30 modules. I am fetching user details in `app.component.ts` to use it throughout the application but I suddenly noticed that user details API runs multiple times on 1 load.

After putting logs in `ngOnInit()` in my `app.component.ts` I found that logs are printing multiple times but it's happening only on server-side rending on the browser it renders only once.

Any idea why `ngOnInit()` calls more than once??

Comment: Hey I don't know the specifics of why exactly this happens but I did fix a similar problem for myself once, I dealt with a redirect for authentication that would go to a SSO page and back to my app and the page kept the objects and promises that were declared in the init. Could serverside rendering be doing something along the lines of rendering the page, and redirecting say from root to /home as a redirect? and attempts to render twice causing the init function to run twice? this doesn't sound right but maybe its a starting point for you?

Comment: Can you please provide more details, what is in your app component ? and any related stuff with app component? Can you please provide the code ?

Comment: You need to give some details on your code and your app architecture. Angular's SSR works fine out of the box

Comment: Can you show some code? Like where is the log instruction, how your AppComponent is bootstrapped?

Comment: Not a solution but maybe a hint. I had a similiar issue in which the ngOnInit of AppComponent was called multiple times. This was triggered by a routing event to a lazy loaded module which was blocked by a guard. This event triggered a redirect to the AppComponent and called ngOnInit once again.

Answer (score 3):

Concept of Angular SSR is that on 1st load of page/URL it renders through server and then transfer data on client side. So Technically it calls all the components, services exist on that page/URL twice.

You can use condition isPlatformBrowser and isPlatformServer method, so you can render only required part on server side. We render only specific thing on SSR which are related to SEO optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

The ngOnInit() hooks only once after all directives are instantiated. If you have subscription inside ngOnInit() and it's not unsubscribed then it will run again if the subscribed data changes. In your case when loading API calls via SSR on the server side, the server does not always wait for the response to come and probably that can be a reason for multiple logs. A suggestion will be to delegate this on the client side using isPlatformBrowser. This is what it looks to me based on the investigation of general SSR flow.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this solved yet, but here is one suggestion:

Add the `subscribe` part in your component itself and remove it from your function which makes HTTP call:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
}

loadData(){
    this.my_service.getData().subscribe(data => this.userDetails = data);
}
```

And in your service, you can have a plain HTTP call:

```
getData() {
    return this.http.get('../your/url')
           .map((res:Response) => res.json());
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Did this answer your question?